# How to validate multiple checkbox to check atleast one in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have seen many example in this forum for multiple check box validation, but my case is different. i have two set of check box with same name and i want to check at least one in each set.

Here is the code

```html
<div class=main>
  question one here *******?
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 4
</div>

<div class=main>
  question two here *******?
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 4
</div>
```

i have tried lot but no luck..any help would be great.

Comment: yeah its applicable for one , but i have two sets like this

Comment: i want to validate, both the question have to checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `every()` to check that every `.main` has at least one checked checkbox

```
var valid = $('.main').toArray().every(function(item) {
    return $(item).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >= 1;
});
```

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
    var valid = $('.main').toArray().every(function(item) {
        return $(item).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length >= 1;
    });
    alert(valid)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=main>
    question one here *******?
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
</div>

<div class=main>
    question two here *******?
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
</div>
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Validate" id="test">
```

Comment: Stop how? Did you see the snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
 function JXX_Check()
{
$('.main').each(function(){
if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length <=0)
{
 alert('atleast select one checkbox in div with index '+ $(this).index()   );
}
});

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='check' onClick='JXX_Check();'/>
<div class=main>
<br>
 question one here *******? 

 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike1"/>checkbox 1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike2"/>checkbox 2<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike3"/>checkbox 3<br>
        </div>

      <div class=main>
<br>
 question two here *******? 
 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike1"/>checkbox 1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike2"/>checkbox 2<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Bike3"/>checkbox 3<br>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:checked` with length to get number of check-boxes checked.

In your case, check `$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length` in particular set.

```
$('.main').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
});
```

```js
$('#checkValid').click(function(){
 $('.main').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0)
    {
      alert("please select at-least one checkbox");  
    }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 question one here *******? 
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
      <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
        </div>
      
      <div class="main">
 question two here *******? 
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
      <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
        </div>

<button id="checkValid">Check valid</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through all .main elements then check their corresponding checkboxes.

```js
$('#check').click(function() {
  $('.main').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length == 0)
      alert($(this).text() + ': no option was checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=main>
  question one here *******?
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 4
</div>

<div class=main>
  question two here *******?
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" />checkbox 4
</div>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `click` event to validate button. Than check that for all `.main` is at least one checkbox input checked:

```js
$('#validate').on('click', function() {  
  $('.main').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
      alert('You have to check at least one answer by question.');
      return false;
    }

    // Your code...
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=main>
    question one here *******?
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
</div>

<div class=main>
    question two here *******?
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]">checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]"> checkbox 4
</div>

<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```